# HTML Bootstrap search bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a search bar for an ebay-type website, but for some reason, the submit button takes the column size of the previous asset, and also goes directly under this asset.
[image]

**CODE**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form class="form">
   
   <!-- SEARCH -->
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group NoPadding"> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
   
   <!-- CATEGORIES -->
   <div class="col-sm-2 form-group NoPadding"> 
    <select name="Categories" class="form-control">
     <option value="0">All Categories</option>
     <option value="1">Electronics</option>
     <option value="2">Food</option>
     <option value="3">Furniture</option>
   </div>
   
   <!-- BUTTON -->
   <div class="col-sm-1 form-group NoPadding"> 
    <input type="submit" class="form-control">
   </div>
   
      </form>
      </div> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close `<select>`. You can reduce `border-radius` of input to get it more closer like ebay.

```css
.NoPadding{
padding:0 !important;
}

input,select{
border-radius:1px !important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form class="form">
   
   <!-- SEARCH -->
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group NoPadding"> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
   
   <!-- CATEGORIES -->
   <div class="col-sm-3 form-group NoPadding"> 
    <select name="Categories" class="form-control">
     <option value="0">All Categories</option>
     <option value="1">Electronics</option>
     <option value="2">Food</option>
     <option value="3">Furniture</option>
          </select>
   </div>
   
   <!-- BUTTON -->
   <div class="col-sm-2 frm-group "> 
    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-primary">
   </div>
   
      </form>
      </div> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply didn't close `select` and `div.form-group`

Also, I would suggest adding `col-md-#`, where # is a number.

See here for the closed tags: https://jsfiddle.net/8z7cL5x0/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your columns in a div with class "row":

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class = "row">
     <form class="form">

      <!-- SEARCH -->
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group NoPadding"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <!-- CATEGORIES -->
      <div class="col-sm-2 form-group NoPadding"> 
        <select name="Categories" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">All Categories</option>
            <option value="1">Electronics</option>
            <option value="2">Food</option>
            <option value="3">Furniture</option>
      </div>

      <!-- BUTTON -->
      <div class="col-sm-1 form-group NoPadding"> 
        <input type="submit" class="form-control">
      </div>

     </form>
    </div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <style>
        .NoPadding {
            padding: 0px !important;
            margin: 0px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- SEARCH -->
                <div class="col-sm-7 form-group NoPadding">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <!-- CATEGORIES -->
                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group NoPadding">
                    <select name="Categories" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">All Categories</option>
                        <option value="1">Electronics</option>
                        <option value="2">Food</option>
                        <option value="3">Furniture</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <!-- BUTTON -->
                <div class="col-sm-2 frm-group NoPadding">
                    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).